# How can I modify a value outside of a closure from the closure?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to change value of `date` in `TimeTravel`. Comments indicate what values I would like, but it's not what I get.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct TimeTravel {
    pub date: Cell<i32>,
}

impl TimeTravel {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        TimeTravel { date: Cell::new(1) }
    }

    pub fn forward(&self) -> &Self {
        let d = self.date.get();
        self.date.set(d + 1);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let travel: TimeTravel = TimeTravel::new();
    println!("{:?}", travel); // 1
    travel.forward();
    println!("{:?}", travel); // 2

    {
        let t1 = travel.clone();
        let first = || {
            t1.forward();
            println!("{:?}", t1); // 3
            t1.forward();
            println!("{:?}", t1); // 4
        };
        first();
    }

    {
        let t2 = travel.clone();
        let second = || {
            t2.forward();
            println!("{:?}", t2); //5
        };
        second();
    }
}
```

However I get this

```
TimeTravel { date: Cell { value: 1 } }
TimeTravel { date: Cell { value: 2 } }
TimeTravel { date: Cell { value: 3 } }
TimeTravel { date: Cell { value: 4 } }
TimeTravel { date: Cell { value: 3 } }
```

If I understand correctly what is happening, I am changing the value in `t1` and `t2`, and not `travel`. How can I change value of `travel` inside a closure?

[Example in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a7a21ff881217d703b53209307254b88&version=nightly)

Comment: If you want to mutate `travel` why are you cloning it? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a7a21ff881217d703b53209307254b88&version=nightly works just fine. Perhaps your real code is more complex and does more complex stuff with the closures?

Comment: Because I'm a complete beginner in rust and cloning is the only way I know to avoid "move" issue, or not running in "already borrowed" or panic. I would like to increment date inside travel so the last one would print 5 (by reference?), which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: And yes, real code is more complex, this is a simplified version of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend going back and re-reading *The Rust Programming Language*, second edition, [specifically the chapter on ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-clone). After that, check out the documentation for [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), emphasis mine:

> A common trait for the ability to **explicitly duplicate** an object.

When you call `.clone()`, you create a new copy of the object, completely distinct from the original. Any changes to the clone do not apply to the original.

As said in the comments, you need to remove all references to `t1` or `t2` and replace them with `travel`:

```
{
    let first = || {
        travel.forward();
        println!("{:?}", travel); // 3
        travel.forward();
        println!("{:?}", travel); // 4
    };
    first();
}

{
    let second = || {
        travel.forward();
        println!("{:?}", travel); //5
    };
    second();
}
```

Comment: I simplified example too much, while this fixed this example it didn't the real code. Real example had `move` closures which needed to change `DateTime`. Had to use `Rc<RefCell<....>>` with `borrow_mut()` to get that working. Thanks anyway